# javascript while loop using functional programming and async

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, while-loop, functional-programming

I am trying to figure out a way to write below code using functional programming.

```
let member_found = [];

// going through 50 or more pagination until 5 are found.
while(member_found.length < 5)
{
  let member = findMember(/* calls selenium commands to visit next page */);
  if(member != undefined)
      member_found.push(member);
}

console.log(member_found) // expecting 5 values but actual is 0.
```

currently, the code goes into infinite loop due to non-blocking nature of js.

Comment: Is `findMember` an async function or doesit take a callback?

Comment: @JonasW.  `let member = findMember(`  he's maybe just missing an await, otherwise that's not an async method..

Comment: it does take callback. That function contains lot of selenium calls to visit multiples pages. For sake of simplicity, I wrote a pseudo code.

Comment: I will answer this question, and before that, one of the bad things of your sample code. `to visit next page` or `a lot of selenium calls`  or `calls selenium commands` is absolutely nothing to do with logic and very unclear context. Perhaps webpage stuff? If you comment to the code. Better not to use words of unclear context.

Comment: Specify the return value of `findMember` It's aweful manner not to speficy the key function. `pseudo code` does not mean to cut the core information. You add unnessary keywrords - pagenation, lots of calls, selnium command, but the most important information is hidden. Rewrite the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap findMember to return a promise and than you can use ES6 async\await capabilities :)

lets say you have `findMember(cb)`
so it will be

```
function promiseFindMember() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => findMember(member => res(member)))
}
```

in this way you will be able to write your function as following

```
function async foo() {
    let members = []
    while(member_found > 5) {
        let member = await promiseFindMember()
        if(member !== undefined) {
            members.push(member)
        }
    }
}
```

I also added an example to catch the concept and to compare between the ideas :)

```js
function dummyCb(cb){
  console.log("Dummy run!")
  setTimeout(cb, 1000)
}

function promiseDummyCb(){
  return new Promise((res, rej) => dummyCb(() => res()))
}


async function async_hello() {
  cb_count = 0
  while(cb_count < 5) {
    await promiseDummyCb()
    cb_count += 1
  }
}

async function hello() {
  cb_count = 0
  while(cb_count < 5) {
    dummyCb()
    cb_count += 1
  }
}



hello()
```

Answer (score 0):

At first ensure that `findMember` always returns something by retrying:

```
const find = cb => findMember(res => res ? cb(res) : find(cb));
```

Now to get an array of a certain length from a callback function we could do the same thing:

```
const fromAsync = (fn, length, cb, arr = []) => arr.length >= length 
   ? cb(arr)
   :  fn(res => fromAsync(fn, length, cb, arr.concat(res)));
```

So you can finally do:

```
fromAsync(find, 10, result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

*PS: there is definitely an easier way of doing this, but you wanted a functional approach...*

Comment: thanks! that was fast. if there is a non-functional way approach. please do share. I will check this tomorrow, its 2 am now :(